# Prevent thunderbird from magnifying image and use it as a link

Tags: html, email, thunderbird

We want to send out an email via Laravel backend with an image in it which is wrapped in an **a** tag, but thunderbird uses the magnifying tool on hover instead of being able to click on the image.

In the source it's like this:

```
<a href=3D"https://test.com/register?invite_id=3D57" style=3D"display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%;">
    <img src=3D"cid:993a9f6af8eed0e1c7cc4e6ae6422f8f@test.com" alt=3D"" style=3D"display: block; width: 100%;">
</a/>
```

And in the mail template:

```
<a href="https://test.com/register?invite_id={{$inviteId}}" style="display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: calc(100%);">
    <img src="https://test.com/public/images/invitation-small.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; width: calc(100%); object-fit: contain;" overflowing="false" shrinktofit="true">
</a>
```

I even added **overflowing="false"** and **shrinktofit="true"** attributes but Thunderbird overwrites them and then it uses its deafult css.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` to each CSS property that's being changed, e.g. `width:calc(100%)!important`? I figure it ignores your `overflowing` and `shrinktofit` attributes because they're nonstandard. Consider the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) and [`width:fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#fit-content) CSS properties instead.

Comment: – If you provide some feedback, I can turn the above into an answer.

Comment: @AdamKatz Gonna try this out tomorrow, but of course we were experimenting with !important flags as well. width:fit-content on the other hand seems to be an interesting solution but considering how strict mail software html and css are, I'm not sure if it's gonna work either. If it does work, You can convert your comment to an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: I ran some tests, and it still produces the same problem: Thunderbird tries to magnify the image when you click on it, instead of taking the user to the link's location.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

I recom, Adam Katz solution and check if applying.

Use !important in your styles.

> Note that **"3D"** is the hex value for the "=" character.

This "3D" will appear in Gmail but the email will render correctly. And it will show up in Outlook.

Please share your result after trying this solution in order to help you further.

Comment: `=` is an escape character in [Quoted-Printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding. `=\n` (equals linebreak) is a QP escape for a no-op (this is used for wrapping to fit [RFC 822](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322 "RFC 5322 updates RFC 822, the .eml spec") without affecting the content). All other escapes are two hexadecimal characters, e.g. `=3D` escapes a bare `=`.